# Bootstrap link disappears after clicking

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a navbar:

```
<div class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-bottom" role="navigation">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li><a id="link-alert" href="#" target="_blank">something that works</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" target="_blank">something</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" target="_blank">something</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" target="_blank">something</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" target="_blank">something</a></li>
        <li class="dropdown">
          <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">projects <b class="caret"></b></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li class="dropdown-header">my projects</li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

After clicking any of the following 'something' hrefs they disappear until I hover over them or clicking anywhere else on the page. How do I fix it?

Comment: It should be styling problem!! Once you click on that it will get focused and `background-color` and `color` might be same which makes you think that it disappeared! Create a fiddle if possible to help on this!

Comment: Its in bootstrap.css. Look for a:focus and then put a new color for that css item in your stylesheet. I had the same problem!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes i agree with kimberlyvoo. Bootstrap.css is putting color for this. You have to override following with your desird color

```
 .navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a:focus
```

Comment: Thanks a lot to you and kimberlyvoo! Problem solved.